# How to replace Gson TypeToken with Moshi?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I want to replace Gson TypeToken to Moshi.

This is Api response:

> {"api":"ApiName","status":"500","errorMessages":[{"errorCd":"errorCode","errorDtl":"Not found XXXXXXXXXX"}]}

This is my current code:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class DataClass<T>(
    @Json(name = "api")
    val api: String,
    @Json(name = "data")
    val data: T?,
    @Json(name = "x")
    val x: X?,
    @Json(name = "status")
    val status: String,
    @Json(name = "y")
    val y: String?,
    @Json(name = "errorMessages")
    val error: List<Error>?,
)


val gson = Gson()
val type = object : TypeToken<DataClass<Unit>>() {}


                response.errorBody()?.charStream()?.let {
                        try {
                            val errorResponse: DataClass<Unit>? = gson.fromJson(it, type)
                            Log.d("SUNIL", "safeApiCallInSide: $errorResponse")
                            error?.error?.first()?.let { error ->
                                ResultEither.Left(
                                    Failure.ServerError(
                                        code = error.cd, errorKey = error.error.toString()
                                    )
                                )
                            } ?: ResultEither.Left(Failure.ServerError(code = "generic_error"))
                        } catch (e: Throwable) {
                            ResultEither.Left(
                                Failure.ServerError(
                                    code = "generic_error", errorKey = "Internal Server Error"
                                )
                            )
                        }

                    }
```

And this is how I am doing but not getting expected result:

```
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
    val t = Types.newParameterizedType(
        DataClass::class.java, Types.newParameterizedType(
            List::class.java,
            Error::class.java
        )
    )

response.errorBody()?.charStream()?.let {
        try {
            val adapter = moshi.adapter<DataClass<List<Error>>>(t)
            val error: ApiResponse<List<Error>>? = adapter.fromJson(it.toString())
            error?.error?.first()?.let { error ->
                ResultEither.Left(
                    Failure.ServerError(
                        code = error.cd, key= error.dtl.toString()
                    )
                )
            } ?: ResultEither.Left(Failure.ServerError(code = "generic_error"))
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            ResultEither.Left(
                Failure.ServerError(
                    code = "generic_error", key= "Internal Server Error"
                )
            )
        }

    }
```

And this is what I am getting:

> BaseNetworkRepository:com.squareup.moshi.JsonEncodingException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at path $

Comment: The error suggests that your JSON is invalid, though it looks OK to me. Did you try setting the lenient setting as it suggested?

Comment: I had tried everything but nothing worked